# How do I change the clustering algorithm for heatmap.2 function in R?

Tags: r

I want to change the clustering method that heatmap.2 uses for the hierarchical clustering. It uses hclust by default, which I want to keep using, but hclust uses the "complete" method and I want to do "average". Heatmap.2 has an hclustfun parameter, but I can't figure out how to use it. I tried

```
heatmap.2(..., hclustfun=hclust(method="average"))
```

but it gave an error that the 'd' argument is required. Heatmap.2 does it's own distance calculation that can be specified with the distfun parameter. I'm not sure how to somehow pass the distances to hclust, or how else to specify a parameter to be passed to hclust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close. As `hclustfun` needs to be a function, the parameter value should indeed be a function, while `hclust(method = "average")` is *calling* `hclust` without specifying `d`. Meanwhile,

```
heatmap.2(x, hclustfun = function(d) hclust(d, method = "average"))
```

works.